# Syntax highlighting for |> for ESS

Tags: r, emacs, syntax-highlighting, ess

I'd like to have the new R operator `|>` get the same syntax coloring as `magrittr::%>%` does in ESS. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options to modify syntax highlighting in `ess-custom`, see <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `ess-R-font-lock-keywords`.

I don't see one that specifically handles the new pipe operator alone (this seems like an option that might get attention if you file a request on github - or there might already be a way to do it precisely with the current custom options that I missed), but a couple alternatives are

```
;; highlight along with current assignment ops
;; ess-R-font-lock-keywords contains (ess-R-fl-assign-ops . t) by default
(with-eval-after-load 'ess
  (cl-pushnew "|>" ess-R-assign-ops :test 'string=))
```

Or add highlighting to all operators by customizing `ess-R-font-lock-keywords` to contain `(ess-fl-keyword:operators . t)`